# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds between theorems 1-3 and 1-4

Tags: compactness

The author says

> If $B \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is compact and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, it is easy to see that $\{ x \} \times B \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is compact.

I would like to know how to prove this.

Comment: If you want to rigorously prove this, just use the definition of compactness.  Consider a cover, and show that there is a finite subcover.

Comment: $\{x\} \times B$ is a topological space (with the subspace topology). What are the open sets?

Comment: Or just consider the obvious homeomorphism $b\mapsto (x,b).$